# Only negative error bars are shown on vega-lite graph

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to add error bars to my vega-lite graph and already have them calculated in a csv. When I try to add them as symmetric bars, only the negative error bars show up in the graph. I copied the method for this kind of error bar from the vega-lite documentation so I am pretty lost on where I went wrong.

I have attached my code and pictures below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "data": {
    "url": "data/Fisher_location137_test.csv"
  },
  "spacing": 15,
  "hconcat": [{"layer":[
      {"width": 750,
      "height": 400,
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "cursor": "pointer"},
        "encoding": {
        "color": {
            "title": "Total (PPA)",
            "field": "Total",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC66", "#09bc8a", "#023057"]}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Variable",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"labelAngle": -45, "title": "Element",
        "grid": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "title": "Total (PPA)",
          "field": "Total",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "fillOpacity": {
      "condition": {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.25
    },
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Variable", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative"},
    ]
      },
      "selection": {"select": {"encodings": ["x"], "type": "single", "value": null}},
    },
        {
        "mark": {
        "type": "errorbar",
        "ticks": {"color": "black"}
        },
        "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"zero": false}},
        "yError": {"field": "stdev"},
        "x":{"field": "Variable", "type": "nominal" }
      }},
    {   "mark": "bar",
        "transform": [
          {"filter": "datum.Total >= 100"},
          {"calculate": "100", "as": "baseline"}
        ],
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "Variable", "type": "ordinal"},
          "y": {"field": "baseline", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Total (PPA)"},
          "y2": {"field": "Total"},
          "color": {"value": "#e45755"},
        "fillOpacity": {
      "condition": {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.25
    },
        }
      },
        {"data": {
         "values": [{}]
      },
         
         "layer":[{
        "mark": "rule",
        "encoding": {
        "y": {"datum": 100}
      },
      }, {
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "align": "right",
          "baseline": "bottom",
          "dx": -2,
          "dy": -2,
          "x": "width",
          "text": "Threshold"
        },
        "encoding": {
        "y": {"datum": 100}
      }
      }]}
    ]},      
    {"layer":[
      {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "click",
            "field": "Sex",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {"range": ["#7a003c", "#FFCC66", "#5b6770"]}
          },
          "value": "lightgray"
        },
        "y": {"field": "Concentration", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Concentration (ug/g)", "aggregate": "mean", "axis": {"orient": "left"}},
        "x": {"title": "Sex", "field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
          "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Sex", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "Concentration", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "mean"},
      {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum"}
    ]
      },
      "selection": {"click": {"encodings": ["color"], "type": "multi"}},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}]},
      {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding":{
        "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "Reference",
        "type": "quantitative",
      },
      "color": {"value": "black"},
      "size": {"value": 3}
      },
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}]},
      {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding":{
        "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "Min",
        "type": "quantitative",
      },
      "color": {"value": "Blue"},
      "size": {"value": 2}
      },
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}]},
     {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding":{
        "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "Max",
        "type": "quantitative",
      },
      "color": {"value": "Red"},
      "size": {"value": 2}
      },
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "select"}}]}
    ],
     "width": 150,
      "height": 400,
    }]
};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sort of static data so we that can atleast render and check your chart else you can share your code over [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: The issue ended up being resolved by just changing to a json format for the data rather than csv.